# Is there a way to optimise the creation of a connection table in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, network-programming, nested-for-loop

I would like to make my code run faster.
I have just started out in data science and decided to do a project.
I downloaded the information that our government made available for the public about the Covid-19 deaths in our country and  made a csv file out of it.
Here is how its structure looked like looked like:
  [table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXJkJ.png)

I formatted this table to be a little bit more manageable.

Here is the structure that I ended up going with:   [table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRGzB.png)

So as you can see from table one, each individual had multiple diseases and I was curious about "how connected" they are so I created [table3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEQBY.png).

Where we have all unique diseases as the columns (in this case that was over 500 columns) and each row represents a unique disease. So we will end up with a 500X500 table.
So with all that said let's get to my question:
How could I make my code, that will result in [table3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEQBY.png) more optimal, than it is now, becouse it takes a bit too much time for it to compile(around 240 seconds with 500 unique diseases).
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from operator import add
import time
start_time = time.time()
#Columns:Id,Disease,Gender,Age
df=pd.read_csv('table2.csv')


headers=df.groupby('Disease').size().to_frame('size').reset_index().sort_values(['size'],ascending=[False])
headers=headers[headers['size']>10].Disease.unique()
network=pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)

for i in range(len(headers)):
    temp_1=df[df.Disease == headers[i]]
    ids=temp_1.Id.unique()
    lista=[0]*len(headers)
    for j in range(len(ids)):
        temp_2=df[df.Id == ids[j]]
        temp_2=temp_2[temp_2.Disease != headers[i]]
        temp_lista=[]
        for k in range(len(headers)):
            temp_3=temp_2[temp_2.Disease == headers[k]]
            temp_lista.append(len(temp_3))
        lista=list(map(add,lista,temp_lista))

    network.loc[i]=lista
network.insert(0,'Diseases',headers)
network.to_csv('table3.csv')
print ("My program took", time.time() - start_time, "to run")
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand how you get to table 3 or what it means. Why does disease 1 match disease 2 or 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Example data;**

```
import pandas 

df1 = pandas.DataFrame({
    'Id' : [1, 2, 3],
    'Diseases' : [['D1', 'D2', 'D3'], ['D2', 'D4', 'D5'], ['D1', 'D2', 'D5']],
    'Age' : [90, 60, 70],
    'Gender': ['Male', 'Female', 'Female']
})

df1
```

Ouput:

```
    Id  Diseases        Age  Gender
0   1   [D1, D2, D3]    90   Male
1   2   [D2, D4, D5]    60   Female
2   3   [D1, D2, D5]    70   Female
```

**2. Create table 2;**

```
df2 = (df1.join(df1['Diseases'].apply(pandas.Series))
          .drop('Diseases', axis=1))

df2 = ( df2.set_index(['Id', 'Age', 'Gender'])
       .stack().reset_index().drop('level_3', axis=1)
       .rename(columns={0: 'Diseases'})
      )

df2
```

Ouput:

```
    Id  Age  Gender Diseases
0   1   90    Male       D1
1   1   90    Male       D2
2   1   90    Male       D3
3   2   60  Female       D2
4   2   60  Female       D4
5   2   60  Female       D5
6   3   70  Female       D1
7   3   70  Female       D2
8   3   70  Female       D5
```

**3. Is this what you are looking for ?**
I don't really understand what you are trying to do here.

```
df3.pivot_table(index=df3.Diseases, columns='Diseases', values='Id', aggfunc='count')
```

Ouput;

```
Diseases     D1      D2      D3      D4     D5
Diseases                    
D1          2.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
D2          NaN     3.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
D3          NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN
D4          NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN
D5          NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     2.0
```